# First order non linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=bx^2-c$$

I need help with solving this equation, the answer Wolfram|Alpha gave me is different than the one I have in my text book.

I tried to do it on my own but I just can't because of the "$c$".

---

Here is the answer given by [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3Dbx%5E2-c):
$$x(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{c}\tanh(\sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{c}\cdot k_1+\sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{c}\cdot t)}{\sqrt{b}}$$

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us both the answers given by Wolfram|Alpha and your textbook, and add that to your question.

Comment: I'm on my mobile so I can't really, but the wolfram one is here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%3Dbx%5E2-c&x=7&y=3 textbook one is too complicated to rewrite it, but it has tg(arctgA-bt) in it where A, and B are some parameters

Comment: The equation is separable and resolves into a standard integral.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it is a separable ODE:
$$\int \frac{1}{bx^2-c}~dx=\int dt \tag{1}$$
Let's evaluate the left hand side integral. Let's factor out $c$ on the denominator:
$$\int \frac{1}{bx^2-c}~dx=-\int \frac{1}{c-bx^2}~dx=-\int \frac{1}{c\left(1-\frac{bx^2}{c}\right)}~dx$$
Therefore, we have:
$$\int \frac{1}{bx^2-c}~dx=-\frac{1}{c} \int \frac{1}{1-\frac{bx^2}{c}}~dx \tag{2}$$
Notice that I put it in this form because it can be put in the form of a well known integral:

> $$\int \frac{1}{1-u^2}~du=\tanh^{-1}(u)+C$$

An obvious substitution to get $(2)$ into that form is to substitute:

$$u=\sqrt{\frac{b}{c}}\cdot x \implies x=\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}\cdot u \implies dx=\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}~du$$

Can you continue? Once you finish evaluating the left-hand side integral, you can evaluate the right hand side integral (It should be very easy), and then obtain an explicit solution for $x(t)$.

Comment: Thank you! I sometimes have problems with definitions...